# How do I get this case statement to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view, I am doing this:

```
<% case @post 
 when @post.has_children? %>
    <% @post.children.each do |child| %> 
            <li><%= link_to child.title, post_path(child)%></li>        
    <% end %>
<% when @post.has_siblings? %>
    <% @post.siblings.where.not(id: @post.id).each do |sibling| %>
            <li><%= link_to sibling.title, post_path(sibling)%></li>                    
    <% end %>
<% when !@post.parent.nil? %>
        <li><%= link_to @post.parent.title, post_path(@post.parent) %></li>
<% else %>
    </ul>
</p>
<p>
    There are no related posts.
</p>
<% end %>
```

Basically what I want to do is I want to check `@post` for a variety of conditions. If it `has_children?`, if it `has_siblings?`, etc.

I don't want the statement to exit if any of the above is true or false.

Once the view loads, it should automatically check for all of these statements. If it finds any of the above true, it should execute the command right below the check.

The issue is when I do this, it always defaults to the `else`. i.e. the case statement doesn't work.

I know I could simply just do a bunch of disjointed if statements, but then the HTML around it gets a bit weird.

Is there a way I can do this with a CASE statement?

**Edit 1**

The reason the `if` statement doesn't work properly, is if I have 3 `if` statements back to back - none of which that interact with each other (that's the only way to cycle through all of the conditions properly), is that the `else` doesn't trigger properly.

E.g. if the first two conditions are true, but the third is not...it will print out `"there are no related posts"`...when that's not the case. It is the case that there are no `parent` posts.

Basically I just want to have a catch-all `related` posts, so I am simply iterating through all of the various options and checking to see if those relations exist. If they do, I am pulling them out and if they don't then they move on. If none exist, then I don't print "there are no related posts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the view is already looking looking complex is a sign that it may be a good idea to refactor the logic out of the view and place it into the Post model where it belongs. Ideally the view(s) should end up looking like this:

```
<%# posts/show.html.erb %>
<% if @post.has_related_posts? %>
   <%= render partial: 'children', collection:  @post.children, as: :child %> 
   <%= render partial: 'siblings', collection:  @post.other_siblings, as: :sibling %> 
   <%= render partial: 'parent', locals:  {parent: @post.parent}%> 
<% else %>
  <p>There are no related posts</p>
<% end %>
```

The paritals:

```
<%# posts/_children.html.erb %>
<li><%= link_to child.title, post_path(child)%></li>


<%# posts/_sibling.html.erb %>
<li><%= link_to sibling.title, post_path(sibling)%></li>

<%# posts/_parent.html.erb %>
<% unless parent.nil? %>
  <li><%= link_to parent.title, post_path(parent) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Then the Post model can organize the logic:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_related_posts?
    !children.to_a.empty? || !other_siblings.to_a.empty? || !parent.nil?
  end

  def children
    self.children || [] # Rails does this automatically, but just for the example
  end

  def other_siblings
    self.siblings.where.not(id: self.id)
  end

  #...
end
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, however IMHO I think it's a better solution.

Comment: is completely on the money here. Rereading what you are looking for, I see that I have answered incorrectly and admit I'm on my phone so was a bit rushed.

Comment: I agree....I think @pete has done an awesome job capturing the intent of my issue.

Comment: What your after is case fall-through which unfortunately ruby doesn't allow unlike other languages. BUT what @pete has suggested is by far a much more sensible solution and in my opinion is exactly how I would want to have it setup. Very clean, clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

Use **IF ELSIF**

```
<% if @post.has_children? %>
  <% @post.children.each do |child| %> 
    <li><%= link_to child.title, post_path(child)%></li>        
  <% end %>
<% elsif @post.has_siblings? %>
  <% @post.siblings.where.not(id: @post.id).each do |sibling| %>
    <li><%= link_to sibling.title, post_path(sibling)%></li>                    
  <% end %>
<% elsif !@post.parent.nil? %>
  <li><%= link_to @post.parent.title, post_path(@post.parent) %></li>
<% else %>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  There are no related posts.
</p>
<% end %>
```

Use **only case** as doz mentioned

```
<% case
  when @post.has_children? %>
    <% @post.children.each do |child| %> 
      <li><%= link_to child.title, post_path(child)%></li>        
  <% end %>
  <% when @post.has_siblings? %>
    <% @post.siblings.where.not(id: @post.id).each do |sibling| %>
      <li><%= link_to sibling.title, post_path(sibling)%></li>                    
  <% end %>
  <% when !@post.parent.nil? %>
    <li><%= link_to @post.parent.title, post_path(@post.parent) %></li>
  <% else %>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p>
      There are no related posts.
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a case statement. Just give case no parameter. Eg instead of `case @post` just use `case`

This is the equivalent of an if statement. And should work for what your trying to achieve

Check out [ruby case statements](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) for some examples